# How do i do the for i in range thing in lua

Tags: lua

I want to know how to do this in Lua

Python:

```py
for i in range(10)
 print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 5):

Lua has a special "numeric for" loop. Two forms exist:

```lua
for i = from, to do ... end
```

equivalent to `for i in range(from, to + 1)` in Python since Python ranges have an *exclusive* end index, and

```lua
for i = from, to, increment do ... end
```

equivalent to `for i in range(from, to + increment, increment)` in Python.

Python's range loop allows omitting the `from` parameter and supplying only the (exclusive) `to` parameter as in your example:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

this is **not** equivalent to

```lua
for i = 1, 10 do print(i) end
```

in Lua: Python will start at 0 and go until 9, whereas the Lua loop starts at 1 and goes until 10. If you *don't* need the index - and only need `to` many iterations - *or* the index is supposed to be the index into a Lua table, string or the like, you should use a loop going from 1 to 10 (both inclusive).

The proper equivalent loop to Python's `for i in range(to)` in Lua is

```lua
for i = 0, to - 1 do ... end
```

---

Finally, you might implement your own `range` iterator. This will exhibit worse performance due to function call overhead though.

```lua
function range(...)
    local n_args = select("#", ...)
    local increment = 1
    if n_args == 1 then
        from, to = 0, ...
    elseif n_args == 2 then
        from, to = ...
    elseif n_args == 3 then
        from, to, increment = ...
    else error"range requires 1-3 arguments" end

    local i = from
    return function()
        if i >= to then return end -- note: to is exclusive
        local prev_i = i
        i = i + increment
        return prev_i
    end
end
```

Usage is just like Python's `range`:

```lua
for i in range(stop) do ... end
for i in range(start, stop) do ... end
for i in range(start, stop, increment) do ... end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as follows:

```
for i=1,10 do print(i) end
```

Lua loops follow the pattern of:

```
for init,max/min value, increment
```